# How to implement run-time licensing?

Tags: licensing, runtime

I need to implement run-time licensing in an embedded protocol stack.

I already have an idea about how to achieve this but I am interested in hearing any alternative approaches, or any pitfalls to watch out for. You can assume that each device running the stack will have a unique hard-coded identifier (MAC address equivalent) and access to some non-volatile storage.

My planned approach is to provide a licence key generated via a hash function from the device identifier which the manufacturer should store in the non-volatile store. The stack will hash the identifier using the same hashing function and verify that it matches the stored key before it will run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure that the license cannot be recomputed easily by an attacker. The most obvious way of doing so is to have the license be a signature of the device identifier using your private key, and have the application verify it using your public key which will be embedded in the software.

You also need to make sure that the software is not tampered with, but this is another story altogether.

Comment: BTW - I recently had to implement a run-time license, though in my case it isn't tied to specific hardware. My solution was to encode all the license information as a JSON object and then encrypt it with my server's private key (what OpenSSL calls RSA_private_encrypt). This is basically signing with the signed cleartext being the entire message instead of a hash, resulting an an opaque bit string that is smaller and easier to transport and verify, than sending the data in the clear and the signed hash.

Comment: An additional twist is that the public key is not embedded in the software, instead it is fetched from the certificate of a public known SSL server, making the whole scheme more portable and supporting easy key replacement. This of course only works if your clients are expected to work on the public internet, otherwise the public key fetch can be easily circumvented - buyer beware.